# Can't get work python-android application on my smartphone

Tags: android, python-3.x, google-api, adb, buildozer

I did a program on the python3, kivy, google-api (for getting access to google drive service) and trying to get it functioning on my android smartphone. The program works fine started on PC but when I ran it through buildozer and got apk-package, the program crashes immediately.

All the time I have used adb with logcat and found out that on Android it needed: httplib2 (or something else, which I get done), then google-auth-oauth (which I got done as well). Now adb screams that there are no module found named 'google.auth'. Can't overcome this problem. Is there any way to tell buildozer where to find all the needed libs or some other way to get it done. Please help me.

Logcat with adb says:

```
08-04 13:23:11.849 13540 13584 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
08-04 13:23:11.849 13540 13584 I python  : AND: Ran string
08-04 13:23:11.849 13540 13584 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
08-04 13:23:12.062 13540 13584 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 21)
08-04 13:23:12.063 13540 13584 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
08-04 13:23:12.070 13540 13584 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.test.tilisync/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_19-08-04_0.txt
08-04 13:23:12.071 13540 13584 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.0
08-04 13:23:12.071 13540 13584 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/org.test.tilisync/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
08-04 13:23:12.071 13540 13584 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.1 (default, Aug  3 2019, 23:00:34) 
08-04 13:23:12.071 13540 13584 I python  : [Clang 6.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang 183abd29fc496f55
08-04 13:23:12.072 13540 13584 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "android_python"
08-04 13:23:12.935 13540 13584 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
08-04 13:23:13.446 13540 13584 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
08-04 13:23:13.504 13540 13584 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
08-04 13:23:13.611 13540 13584 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
08-04 13:23:13.648 13540 13584 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
08-04 13:23:13.650 13540 13584 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
08-04 13:23:13.650 13540 13584 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 v1.r20p0-01rel0.9a7fca3f7dd712a473937294a8ae24b1'>
08-04 13:23:13.651 13540 13584 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'ARM'>
08-04 13:23:13.651 13540 13584 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Mali-T830'>
08-04 13:23:13.651 13540 13584 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
08-04 13:23:13.652 13540 13584 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
08-04 13:23:13.652 13540 13584 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
08-04 13:23:13.702 13540 13584 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
08-04 13:23:13.703 13540 13584 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
08-04 13:23:13.939 13540 13584 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
08-04 13:23:13.939 13540 13584 I python  :    File "/home/anton/Documents/tiliSync/tiliSync/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 15, in <module>
08-04 13:23:13.940 13540 13584 I python  :    File "/home/anton/Documents/tiliSync/tiliSync/.buildozer/android/app/gapi_cls.py", line 5, in <module>
08-04 13:23:13.941 13540 13584 I python  :    File "/home/anton/Documents/tiliSync/tiliSync/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/tilisync/google_auth_oauthlib/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
08-04 13:23:13.941 13540 13584 I python  :    File "/home/anton/Documents/tiliSync/tiliSync/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/tilisync/google_auth_oauthlib/interactive.py", line 24, in <module>
08-04 13:23:13.942 13540 13584 I python  :    File "/home/anton/Documents/tiliSync/tiliSync/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/tilisync/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 67, in <module>
08-04 13:23:13.943 13540 13584 I python  :  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.auth'
08-04 13:23:13.943 13540 13584 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

Buildozer spec:

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,google-api-python-client,google-oauth,google-auth-oauthlib,httplib2,uritemplate,openssl,google-cloud-storage,google-cloud-core,google-auth, google-auth-httplib2
```

App directory:

```
anton@anton-VirtualBox:~/Documents/tiliSync/tiliSync$ ls
bin             client_secret.json  gapi_cls.py    google_auth-1.6.3-py3.5-nspkg.pth  lib      my.kv        six.py       tilit.txt     tst_upload.txt
buildozer.spec  debug_log           gapi_tests.py  google_auth_httplib2.py            main.py  __pycache__  tiliSync.py  token.pickle  venv
```

Think that there are some problem with:

```
from google-auth-oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
```

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 using python3